# Has an electoral ceiling ever been implemented or proposed?

Tags: voting-systems

The concept of [electoral threshold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_threshold) is well established. What about the upper limit though? I mean a reduction of possible party/block power grasp to say 40% and transferring power to smaller players.

Is this a known idea? Is there a trace of it in the political thought history or real life perhaps?